# jQuery plugin with chained methods

Tags: jquery

I am building a technical analysis plugin and am looking for some guidance.

I want to do something like this:

```
var ohlcList; //a list of stock data points, open high low close

var bars = $().indicators(ohlcList)
                .MA(50)
                .MA(100)
                .MACD(12, 26, 9);
```

The plugin would loop through `ohlcList` applying the indicators MA(50), MA(100), and MACD(12, 26, 9) to it. The results would look like:

```
bars = [{ Open: 2, High: 3, Low: 1, Close: 2, MA_50: 2, MA_100: 3, MACD_12_26_9: 4 }, {...}]
```

Any ideas on how the plugin would look?

Comment: If it was me would pass in the indicators wanted as part of the plugin options config

Answer (score 0):

You can chain functions with jQuery, and you combine that with `return this;`. That way the next function knows you're still refering to the original object.

```
$.fn.example(someNumber){
    // `this` now is the object you applies it too

    // Very basic example of what you can do now:
    this.counter = this.counter+1 || 0; // keep an internal counter
    this[someNumber] = this.counter;
    // Do things with it as you please

    return this; // now the next method call knows what you're talking about.
}
```